# How should I select a price for a landscape image?

Tags: landscape, pricing

Ive been asked to sell one of my landscape images. The request has come from an architect who is redeveloping a part of a hospital Trust. The trust have chosen my image and it will be enlarged to approx 5metres x 3metres. How much do I charge for hi res file of 20mb?

Comment: I'd say it's up to you, it doesn't depend on file size.

Comment: How much skill and artistry went into this image? How easy would it be to reproduce? Is there any non-monetary value to you in having your image selected?

Comment: Also consider whether or not they will be displaying your name along with the photo.  If it is not displayed, make them pay extra, possibly double, because if they DO give you credit, then that could be a source of good advertising, and possibly more income.

Comment: I'd like to add this as comment, but my reputation doesn't allow me to post yet. If I was in your position, I'd think about it on a different way. I'd suggest you a very cheap price, as this image will be your free advertisment in a public place, for many many years. Just add a small signature of your name on one of the corners. Hope I helped you, that's the way I would think about this. I don't know how well known or famous you might be, but this picture will be a good addition on your CV and portfolio.

Comment: I suspect when you say "sell", what you actually mean is that you are being asked to consider "licensing" the use of your image to the hospital trust.  Whatever you do, and whatever price you decide, you should ensure that you retain copyright of your orignal image, and put together a license contract that the trust signs agreeing that they have a non-exclusive right to use your image for the sole purpose of their banner.  If they want exclusive rights, or they want to use the same image on e.g. their website, then that should affect the price you decide.  Google "license my images" or similar

Comment: @CountIblis This is a website where people provide free consultancy services. Both answers and questions are covered by the relevant site licence. People may charge up to the maximum allowed by the licence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the default if you have no idea. Ask the client what their budget is for the piece. When they answer with the price if that number is suitable to you take it.

Once you sell a few more like this you'll get a knack for it, and have better idea of what your pricing should be.

Answer (score 0):

I will start by saying 'a beautiful body perishes but a work of art does not.' Now consider the expenses or investment made on such a beautiful art piece that will last for eternity and at least price just a little above the money invested. But remember don't price according to your talent given you because you are also creating a platform to advertise yourself. Thank you.